# Starting interactive terminal in a Python image container

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I downloaded an image `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6` from this [link](https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/python) and I am trying to open an interactive terminal into this container image.

I  tried the following tree approaches and none of these opens up any interactive terminal:

1. `docker run -it public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6 bash`
2. `docker run -it public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6 /bin/bash`
3. `docker run -it public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6 sh`

This is the output I get in all the above three commands, it seems to be displaying the container logs rather than opening up an interactive terminal within the container image

`INFO[0000] exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)`

Please help

Comment: Have you tried running `python` instead of `bash`?

Comment: Nope, not tried yet. I don't need to execute any python commands actually, I need to install a few unix executables and hence looking for an interactive terminal

Comment: @user182944 That is not how you do that. You create your own `Dockerfile` which is build upon `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6` and then in your Dockerfile you install the software that you need and run this image.

Comment: Agreed, but some packages that I need are breaking and hence its easier to open an interactive terminal and try it out manually, then will convert it into a working Dockerfile

Answer (score 8):

ok, here's the answer 1 year and 3 months late ;-) but hopefully will be useful for someone.

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
```

You just need to overwrite **entrypoint**, which was set to a shell script in the base image:

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/blob/python3.9/Dockerfile.python3.9#L18

Answer (score 0):

The image is not designed for interactive use. Once you have built an image with an actual lambda, call it with the name of that lambda as the first argument.